# How to set and delete cookies from WebBrowser Control for arbitrary domains

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

How can I set and delete cookies for a domain in webbrowser control without using Javascript (*which doesn't allow to set / delete cookies without navigating to the website first.*)

Comment: What is your requirement/scenario for this?  "From webbrowser control" might not be necessary.  Do you have control of the site?  If you do, you can add and remove cookies from the HttpRequest, and that API allows you to specify the cookie domain.

Comment: I have a browser and I want to add the ability to modify all the cookies for a given website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to accomplish this task by combining these 2:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815718

and INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have gone through the URLs but i did not find any solution. can you please give me the brief solution. I got struck with same problem from last 10 days

Comment: @dr.evil Can you please provide a summary about what you did to resolve this?... Link only answers are not so good in SO.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Storm8
{
    class Program
    {

        [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);

        [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool InternetGetCookie(
            string lpszUrlName,
            string lpszCookieName,
            StringBuilder lpszCookieData,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            ref int lpdwSize
        );

        [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool InternetSetCookie(
            string lpszUrlName,
            string lpszCookieName,
            string lpszCookieData
        );

        [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool InternetSetOption(
            int hInternet,
            int dwOption,
            string lpBuffer,
            int dwBufferLength
        );



        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InternetSetOption(0, 42, null, 0);
            InternetSetCookie("http://domain.name.com", "cookiename", "cookievalue");

            WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
            string testUrl = "http://domain.name.com/fight.php?showAttackBg=true";
            string additionalHeaders = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit /528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7A341" + Environment.NewLine +
                "Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5" + Environment.NewLine +
                "Accept-Language: en-gb";

            if (wb.Document == null)
                wb.Navigate(testUrl, null, null, additionalHeaders);

            while (wb.Document == null)
                Application.DoEvents();

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

[Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/76a38eee-3ef6-4993-a54d-3fecc4eb6cff)

Comment: I did not understand.. how can I delete a cookie from a URI?

Answer (score 0):

IE Uses WinInet functions for networking so you can use [WinInet's cookie functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384321(VS.85).aspx) to change the cookie.
Update: The requirement demands per-process setting. Since the cache folder location is not stored in IE settings registry key IDocHostUIHandler2::GetOverrideKeyPath won't work. I don't know a way to customize the cookie folder location at the process level except to hook all WinInet APIs (and stuck with updating application to accommodate future WinInet APIs).

Comment: Isn't that for whole IE? I don't want to delete users' browser cookies for IE, it should be something only for the current application's hosted web control. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you want to isolate your application's cookies you need to override the Cache directory registry setting via IDocHostUIHandler2::GetOverrideKeyPath

Comment: I'm not positive that the GetOverrideKeyPath trick would even work.

You'll want to use InternetSetCookieEx either way.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the IE cache folder setting isn't under IE settings. It is under shell folder settings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a finer solution that only clears cookies (C/C++):

```
#include <wininet.h>
#include <winineti.h>
...
DWORD dwSuppress = INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST;
InternetSetOption(0, INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR, &dwSuppress, sizeof(DWORD));
```

All credits to [this blog post](http://mdb-blog.blogspot.fr/2013/02/c-winforms-webbrowser-clear-all-cookies.html) (C#). Don't forget to check the documentation for [InternetSetOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: It does not clear cookies. It does something else. During your process, normally persistent cookies will not be persisted. But cookies that are already there, already stored, are not affected at all. Just try to run and view the actual list of cookies in Internet Options.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a blog post on how do delete cookies in WebBrowser control using wininet.

http://web.archive.org/web/20140219074039/http://www.alphatecit.com.au/code-snippets/facebook-c-sdk-multiple-login-problem-resolved

Comment: The link is also now dead. Please include a bare bones solution when posting an external link.

Answer (score -4):

You can't delete cookies for a domain other than the domain of the current site.

To do what you are asking requires you have access to the machine (i.e. toolbar installed). Even then it's kludgy.

The only exception is if you are on a domain where the cookie is using the * wildcard, for example *.stackoverflow.com. If you change a cookie with the wildcard, then all the child sub domains (i.e. blog.stackoverflow.com) will have access and see the change that was made to the cookie.

Comment: From "Webrowser Control", this is not a web application it's Winforms.