# Clear Cookies Cache for Multiple WebBrowser Control with WinInet in Winform Application

Tags: winforms, caching, cookies, controls, browser

i need to Clear cache and Cookies for all WebBrowser Controls in a tabbed WebBrowser.
I can't use run32dll to do this.

After googled a little i found this :

```
    private const int INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION = 42;

    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength); 

InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

First of all what does it clear? Cookie only or cache too?

Then Does it delete the cache and cookies for all webControl in the controls?

I need to delete cache for some website before open a tab and then when i need to close all the tabs i want clear cache and cookie for all webControl.

If i call `tabs.TabPages.clear();` and i close all webBrowsers did i clean Cache and Session?

Thanks

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688991/how-to-set-and-delete-cookies-from-webbrowser-control-for-arbitrary-domains