# Working with cookies using WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, cookies, webbrowser-control

As part of the functionality of my program, I need to be able to log into a website and then navigate to the user-only sections.

The problem is that I need to do this for multiple sites, and also for different accounts on the same site.

So my question is, how can I delete the cookies from the WebBrowser control?

So I can login ====> access content ====> delete cookies to enable further login sessions.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set and delete cookies from WebBrowser Control for arbitrary domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688991/how-to-set-and-delete-cookies-from-webbrowser-control-for-arbitrary-domains)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it down following this:

http://www.alphatecit.com.au/code-snippets/facebook-c-sdk-multiple-login-problem-resolved/