# Use CookieContainer with WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, cookiecontainer

I've created a `CookieContainer` and stored the cookies from a `HttpWebRequest` in it. Is there a way I can use this CookieContainer on a WebBrowser control?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185171/use-cookies-from-cookiecontainer-in-webbrowser and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688991/how-to-set-and-delete-cookies-from-webbrowser-control-for-arbitrary-domains

Comment: First one didn't work. But didn't find the second one before. I'll have a look at that now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cookie value from the container with [GetCookieHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.getcookieheader.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks. Got the cookie in a string now. Any idea how to set the cookie on the WebBrowser?

Comment: I have no experience with webbrowser since I prefer using HTTPWebRequst. Anyways, you can try setting the cookie : webborwser.document.cookie